# Append audio samples to AVAssetWriter from streaming

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm using a project when I'm recording video from the camera, but the audio comes from streaming. The audio frames obviously are not synchronised with video frames. 
If I use AVAssetWriter without video, recording audio frames from streaming it is working fine. But if I append video and audio frames, I can't hear anything.

Here it is the method for convert the audiodata from the stream to CMsampleBuffer

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription monoStreamFormat = [self getAudioDescription];


CMFormatDescriptionRef format = NULL;
OSStatus status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &monoStreamFormat, 0,NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &format);
if (status != noErr) {
    // really shouldn't happen
    return nil;
}

CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, 44100.0), kCMTimeZero, kCMTimeInvalid };


CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = NULL;
status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, numSamples, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &sampleBuffer);
if (status != noErr) {
    // couldn't create the sample alguiebuffer
    NSLog(@"Failed to create sample buffer");
    CFRelease(format);
    return nil;
}

// add the samples to the buffer
status = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(sampleBuffer,
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                        0,
                                                        samples);
if (status != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to add samples to sample buffer");
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    CFRelease(format);
    return nil;
}
```

I don't know if this is related with the timing. But I would like to append the audio frames from the first second of the video.

is it that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this

```
uint64_t _hostTimeToNSFactor = hostTime;

_hostTimeToNSFactor *= info.numer;
_hostTimeToNSFactor /= info.denom;

uint64_t timeNS = (uint64_t)(hostTime * _hostTimeToNSFactor);
CMTime presentationTime = self.initialiseTime;//CMTimeMake(timeNS, 1000000000);
CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, 44100), presentationTime, kCMTimeInvalid };
```

Comment: Im having the exact same issue. Can you share your code? the solution is hard to understand where those variables are coming from.

Comment: @omarojo initialiseTime is the first video frame timestamp of the recording session. You need to keep adding audio from that timestamp

Comment: @Pablo Martinez: Can you please share you code, I am stuck since 1 week, We want to record audio which is coming from webRTC portal. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes audio is coming from server side.
We need to record client video + audio + server audio

Comment: We record phone video and audio using AVAssetsWriter but could not able to record stream audio

Comment: @PabloMartinez: Can you please give the answer ?

Comment: @Hardik1344 the code for that is quite a lot. We are able to record stream audio, but there are few pieces to have in mind

Comment: @PabloMartinez: Is the code available on github or anywhere? so we can show it

Comment: @Hardik1344 unfortunately this code is not open source. But I’m open to discuss a possible colaboration.

Comment: @PabloMartinez:Thanks for this,We done local recording using AVAssetswriter with audio and video.But we have to record incoming audio along with local audio and video.
Streaming audio comes from webRTC audio stream .

Comment: @PabloMartinez Are you getting remote stream from nsoutputstream?

Comment: Outputstream is to send data. Inputstream is the data coming from a remote source @iosdev1111